# Does conv_transpose2d do a convolution or a cross-correlation operator?

Tags: pytorch, torch

The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#convtranspose2d) for the nn mentions it does a cross-correlation, however, my results indicate it does a convolution operator.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
im = torch.Tensor([[0,1],[2,3]]).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)

kernel = torch.Tensor([[0,1,2],[3,4,5], [6,7,8]]).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
op = F.conv_transpose2d(im, kernel, stride=2)
print(op)
```

It outputs :

```
tensor([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
          [ 0.,  2., 10., 10., 14.],
          [ 6.,  8., 19., 12., 15.],
          [12., 14., 34., 21., 24.]]]])
```

which would be the result if there was a convolution, I had expected the correlation result to be:

```
tensor([[[[ 0.,  0.,  8.,  7.,  6.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  4.,  3.],
          [16., 14., 38., 22., 18.],
          [10.,  8., 21., 12.,  9.],
          [ 4.,  2.,  6.,  3.,  0.]]]])
```

Did I misunderstand something?